# youtube-dl how to convert video format quality i hav'ent find solution

Tags: youtube, file-format, youtube-dl, video-conversion

I have `youtube dl` and I have a problem with video quality. I have tried `youtube-dl` on `odysee` but the problem is the video has one format only and with best format option I can't change the quality video lowest... I have tried to search for a solution on the internet but have find nothing. I've tried with option `max-file` size but it doesn't work either. It tells me that the file is bigger than the size I'm asking (file is larger that max-file size).

So I'm thinking would it be possible to download the video normally and then convert the video to lower quality? Because I've seen that you can apparently change the format from mp4 to avi for example but is it possible to download the video and after that to go automatically converting it from mp4 1080p to mp4 480p for example? So that it takes up less space on the hard disk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shrink mp4 video file size by 92%?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046287/how-to-shrink-mp4-video-file-size-by-92)

Answer (score 0):

`youtube-dl` is no longer supported and its latest release is from `17 December 2021`.

A good alternative is a fork called [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp).

Here are some options that may be useful for you:

```
# Download the best video available but no better than 480p,
# or the worst video if there is no video under 480p
$ yt-dlp -f "bv*[height<=480]+ba/b[height<=480] / wv*+ba/w"

# Download the best video available with the largest height but no better than 480p,
# or the best video with the smallest resolution if there is no video under 480p
$ yt-dlp -S "height:480"

# Download the best video available with the largest resolution but no better than 480p,
# or the best video with the smallest resolution if there is no video under 480p
# Resolution is determined by using the smallest dimension.
# So this works correctly for vertical videos as well
$ yt-dlp -S "res:480"

# Download the best video (that also has audio) but no bigger than 50 MB,
# or the worst video (that also has audio) if there is no video under 50 MB
$ yt-dlp -f "b[filesize<50M] / w"

# Download largest video (that also has audio) but no bigger than 50 MB,
# or the smallest video (that also has audio) if there is no video under 50 MB
$ yt-dlp -f "b" -S "filesize:50M"

# Download best video (that also has audio) that is closest in size to 50 MB
$ yt-dlp -f "b" -S "filesize~50M"
```

If the problem is that the source has only high quality videos, you will have to do some converting after the download. You can also check this question: [How can I reduce a video's size with ffmpeg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: yes i have also yt-dlp i will test that but i think the probleme is connverting i will watch the link

Comment: Check it and update your question with more details if the problem continues. An example will help too.